# Can't import multiple modules using 'import'

Tags: node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I'm trying to import classes from a .js file, but when I run the program it seems to have a Syntax error. Here's my code:

`import { RTUser, RTEvent, RTPurchase, RTMedia } from "./defs";`

and here's the error that's being shown in the console.

```
/Users/williamg/retake/api/RTKit/index.js:34
import { RTUser, RTEvent, RTPurchase, RTMedia } from "./defs";
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.wrappedLoad [as _load] (/Users/williamg/retake/api/node_modules/newrelic/lib/shimmer.js:372:38)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
```

An example of an export in the `defs.js` file is:

`export class RTPurchase extends RTClass { }`

The files are built from `.ts` files using `tsc`.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you running in node ? use `"module": "commonjs",`

Answer (score 0):

Try Using var esLint = require('./ejbs');